# How to prevent auto scroll smooth while any other link to page fires

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps, svelte

The question is how to prevent scrolling or stop it immediately while user click to another page ?

Atm I'm developing PWA app, the scroll button is showing up while the scroll for some time the content on the page, yet there is a bug when the user is scrolling and try to click the link for other page with different data, the page is loading in a half. In that case the main screen is not totally hidden, and the new one is showing in half of the page.

Is there anything to prevent such situation ? E.g stop scroll action when user use any href link for other page ?

Here is the code that is running when user click scroll to top:

```
const scrollTop = () => {
    // document.querySelector("#top").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto" });
    document.querySelector("#top").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
};

<div
   class="back-to-top"
   on:click={scrollTop}
 >
<img src="/images/arrow-upward-outline.svg" alt="up" />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"other page"*?  Have you tried to: *"on navigation - always do a scrollTo({top: 0})"* ... Would it help to cancel the ongoing scroll animation - and instead snap the page to top?

Comment: other page means in this scenario - another route page :)